# Laravel three table pivot

Tags: mysql, laravel, many-to-many, pivot, eloquent

## Music Discovery website

### Summary

I am using **Laravel** to create a music search/discovery website. In short **Artists** have many **Albums** which have many **Tracks**. A **User** has many **Tags** associated with the **Tracks**. **TAGGING CAN ONLY BE DONE ON TRACKS, NOT ALBUMS OR ARTISTS.**

A user visits the website and can search for a set of *tags* e.g. **"Happy", "Party", "School"**. A list of tracks is returned along with some other details.

The tracks are tagged in the first place by users. A user should be able to see all the tracks that they have tagged and be able to search/ filter based on tags too.

### The Issue

With my current setup (see table structure below) there is no way to tell which user tagged a particular track. I am thinking about merging the two tables **tag_track** and **tag_user** into one. The new table would have a structure of:

#### Tag_Track_User table

```
Tag_ID
Track_ID
User_ID
```

### My Questions

1. If I do this, what relationships do I set up on the models
2. How can I get all tracks associated with a tag (*tags.text*)

### Current Table Structures

#### Users table

```
User_ID (UNI)
User_Name
```

#### Artists table

```
Artist_ID (UNI)
Artist_Name
```

#### Album table

```
Album_ID (UNI)
Album_Title
Artist_ID
```

#### Track table

```
Track_ID (UNI)
Track_title
Album_ID
```

#### Tag table

```
Tag_ID (UNI)
Tag_text (UNI)
```

#### Tag_Track table

```
Tag_ID
Track_ID
```

#### Tag_User table

```
Tag_ID
User_ID
```

### Model Structures

#### Artist model

Has many **Tlbums**

#### Album model

Belongs to **Album**
Has many **Tracks**

#### Track model

Belongs to **Album**
Has many **Tracks**

#### User model

Belongs to many **Tags**

#### Tag model

Belongs to many **Tracks**
Belongs to many **Users**

Comment: Why would you want to know who tagged a track? Are those tags personal or public? Describe what are those tags and how users assign them to tracks

Comment: I've updated the question (added two paragraphs at the top to explain the 'situation')

Comment: OK so tags are public, still you don't say why you would like to know who tagged the track. Anyway you can simply add 3rd fk field on the pivot table tag_track to track the user

Comment: Because it is a music discovery website, you can find other people who have tagged a song in a similar manner to yourself, thus you may like their music. Could you give examples of how to reference the models with regards to the relationship.

Answer (score 3):

You're right about the pivot table. It must contain 3 keys, as in this situation tags can't exist without a user or a track. So it's a relationship between 3 models.

So here's all you need (I'm skipping artist and album relations ofc):

```
// pivot table tag_track_user: tag_id, track_id, user_id, id, timestamps

// Tag model
public function users()
{
    // by default only 2 keys are on the pivot, so lets add the third
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'tag_track_user')->withPivot('track_id'); 
}

public function tracks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Track', 'tag_track_user')->withPivot('user_id'); 
}
------------
// Track model
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tag_track_user')->withPivot('user_id'); 
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'tag_track_user')->withPivot('tag_id'); 
}
------------
// User model
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tag_track_user')->withPivot('track_id');
}

public function tracks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Track', 'tag_track_user')->withPivot('tag_id'); 
}
```

Now, with this setup you can get everything you want:

```
$user->tags->first()->users; // other users who used given tag
Tag::where('name','happy')->first()->tracks; // all tracks tagged 'happy'
$user->tracks()->where('title','Happy')->first()->tags; // all tags attached to song Happy
$user->tags->load('tracks')->fetch('tracks')->collapse(); // array of all the tracks related to all tags of a user (as arrays not models)
etc.
```

Of course the above will cause a few db queries, but that's normal.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions yet I "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$tags". This is what I am using that causes that error: "$user = User::whereUsername('mstnorris');
    $user->tags->first()->users;"

Comment: Then you don't have properly defined tags on the User model or the pivot table is not exactly as it should be or the keys there are wrong... The code I pasted works for sure, so double check your models and table

Comment: The code you provided at the bottom, is that it in its entirety? I have set up a route 'test' and in that closure I want to try it out for myself using my username so I pull all the tags and tracks associated with me. How do I do that?

Comment: $user = User::whereUsername('You')->first(); then the rest.. Play with it in 'artisan tinker' it's waaay easier than in the browser. If you don't know this tool you can check https://laracasts.com/lessons/tinkering-with-boris (probably paid video, but Jeff's laracasts is worth it)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. I had ->get() instead of ->first(). What is the difference? I already subscribe to laracasts, they're great aren't they! Also, how do I return the tag and track details (not just the IDs)?

Comment: Loading relation means loading related models (not only ids). Laracasts is a one man army - Jeffrey Way, it's good indeed. And lastly get() returns Eloquent\Collection of models and first()/find($id) returns single Eloquent\Model

Comment: When I for example return this "return $user->tracks()->where('title','Mr. Brightside')->first()->tags;" I get one result as there is only one tag in the database which is great. The IDs of the pivot table are returned, is there a way to get it to also return the information from the related tables too?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50949/discussion-between-deczo-and-mike)